# Read OneDrive files using Microsoft graph api

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to access my OneDrive (personal account) files using the Microsoft Graph API but I can't get it to work. I have read for days now whithout luck.
I'm using the "[Client Credentials Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds)". I have created an application in the Application Registration Portal and I have set application permissions. It works fine to get a token but when I try to read the root of OneDrive using this token it says "Access Denied", "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.". This happens when I use the v2.0 version to get the token and then the v1.0 version to access OneDrive.
I.e. I use this URL to get the token:
*https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token*
and this URL to get the OneDrive root:
*https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drive/root?$expand=thumbnails,children($expand=thumbnails)*

It works fine when I do the "[Authorization Code Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code)".

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For personal accounts and data associated to personal accounts (like a personal OneDrive), only delegated (authorization code flow) is supported.  Client credential flow is not supported here.  Client credential flow is only supported for commercial (Azure AD) scenarios.

Do you have a particular scenario in mind as to why you need to use client credentials flow (versus authorization code flow) against personal OneDrive?

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the answer. The reason I want to use client credential flow is because i want to create a service that will sync videos from my network camera to my OneDrive. This service shall run on a Raspberry pi in a docker container (i.e. on linux) so I can't have an auth flow with a browser pop-up. As I understand the only flow that supports this scenario is client credentials.

Comment: Dan, do you know how I can solve my scenario without a browser popup?

Comment: Take a look at the device profile as described by Vittorio here: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/12/02/new-adal-3-x-previewdevice-profile-linux-and-os-x-sample/.  You'll need to use ADAL (which uses the v1 authorize/token endpoints), but this should still work for you.  There's also this sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-deviceprofile

Comment: Hi Dan,
I tried the samples you pointed to but they didn't work using personal microsoft account. I get this error:

Correlation ID: bcdafa4f-d332-4acc-af2b-42433d834866
Timestamp: 2017-11-12 20:25:58Z
AADSTS50020: We are unable to issue tokens from this api version for a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this.

Comment: Sorry for the suggestion here - unfortunately the device flow is not supported on the v2.0 protocol.  I'll need to ask someone else to take a look at this, to see if there are any other options here.

Comment: can you explain when something is an Azure AD vs personal scenario?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Personal represents your personal OneDrive which you sign in to using your personal account (Microsoft Account) - like an outlook.com or hotmail.com account.  The commercial, Azure AD version would be when you sign in to your organization, and access your OneDrive for business.  Hope this helps.